# TS Property does not exist after just checking its existence

Tags: typescript

I have an object that a user passes, could be any kind of object. In the function I check for a prop, and if that exist I want to return it:

```
if ('id' in payload) return payload.id
```

I have declared `payload` as `object`.
But TypeScript gives me the error:

> [ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.
>
> any

Even though **I just checked if it exists or not**...

Any advise?

Comment: What is the declared type of `payload` ?

Comment: I declare it 'object'

Comment: Did you tried calling it as an array like ,`payload['id']`?

Comment: you have to use `obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)` and `obj[propertyName]`. have a look on the function i posted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator will only change the type of a variable (ie act as a type-guard) if that variable is of a union type (it will narrow the type of the variable to a union of all members that contain the key).

You can either declare the type of payload to be a union in which a member contains the field:

```
let payload: object | { id: number };
if ('id' in payload)  payload.id // ok now
```

Or you can use a type assertion:

```
let payload: object;
if ('id' in payload)  (payload as { id: number }).id // ok now
```

You could also use an index access, but this will only work if `noImplicitAny` is not specified as a compiler option. (This option prevents all sort of important errors so I would not deactivate it)

```
let payload: object;
if ('id' in payload)  payload['id'] // ok if noImplicitAny  is not specified
```

Comment: Your first example is wrong, that's an OR, not union. It should be `let payload: object & { id: number };`

Comment: @ritaj no, union types are alternates (`|`) intersection are both types (`&`) see here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html I always got them mixed up at first :). I wanted to keep the `object` if the check is not performed not add `id` to the type (it might not be present if a check is required, as mentioned in the original question)

Comment: Oh well, thank you. Mixed up my nomenclature. But it should still be an intersection of types, since the OP wants the type to be an object with that special `id` attribute. Not object OR the object with ONLY id as an attribute.

Comment: @ritaj The object needs to be any kind of object with any kind of props. And maybe there is a prop called `id`. If there is a prop called `id` I wanna return that. If not go to the next line.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why you need an intersection `&`, not the union `|`

Comment: Alternatively, you could do it like this: `let payload: object | ({ id: number } & object);` Which I think will work the best for you.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks so much!!!
@TitianCernicova-Dragomir Could you edit your answer?

Comment: @ritaj `object` will not add anything to `{ id: number} & object` is the same as `{id: number}` from the handbook : object is a type that represents the non-primitive type, i.e. any thing that is not number, string, boolean, symbol, null, or undefined.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @mesqueeb not sure what I should add, I do not believe `object | ({ id: number } & object)` to be substantially different to `object | { id: number }`. I am willing to be wrong, but I don't see what you can do with one but not the other ..

Comment: @ritaj For example: `let payload: object | { id: number };
if ('id' in payload) { let o: object = payload; /* payload is { id: number } and is assignable to object }`

Comment: It doesn't really make any difference, really, until the OP decides to type their payload object to some kind of interface, which they already should be doing. Then it will make all the difference. Change from `object` to `IMyInterface` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

here is my working TS function for that

```
/**
* function to get value from dynamic object by property name if the property exists.
* (if the property does not exists it returns undefined)
*
* @param {object} obj [the object you want to check]
* @param {string} property [the name of the property you want to get the value from]
* @returns {any|undefined}
**/
let getValueByProperty  = (obj: object, property: string): any => {
  // initalize out as undefined;
  let out: any;
  // check if property exists
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property){
    // get value from object.property with an array like call
    out = obj[property];
  }
  // return the value stored to out
  return out;
}
```